# Delete statement not working for a Decimal column

Tags: sql, teradata, sql-delete

I am working on a delete statement as below:

```
DEL FROM X.SALES1
WHERE CAST(SALES_T_ID AS DECIMAL(18,0)) IN(

SEL CAST(T1.SALES_T_ID AS DECIMAL(18,0) )FROM
(
SEL *  FROM 
X.SALES1
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY SALES_SRC_ID,DSTC ORDER BY UPDATED_DATE_TIMESTAMP DESC) >1
) T1
) ;
```

The above delete should keep the latest record and delete the rest.
However, it is deleting all the records.
I have checked the inner query and working fine, selecting only the records other than the latest updated one.
But i am not able to understand why it's deleting all the records?

Below is the Table structure:

```
CREATE SET TABLE X.SALES1 ,FALLBACK ,
     NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
     NO AFTER JOURNAL,
     CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
     DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO,
     MAP = TD_MAP1
     (
      SALES_T_ID DECIMAL(18,0),
      SALES_TRANS_NUM VARCHAR(30) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      SALES_SRC_ID VARCHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
      SALES_TRANS_START_DTTM TIMESTAMP(0),
      ST_EXPECTED_CLOSE_DTTM TIMESTAMP(0),
      ST_ACTUAL_CLOSE_DTTM TIMESTAMP(0),
      ST_ACT_CONT_DTTM TIMESTAMP(0),
      ST_EXP_CONT_CLS_DTTM TIMESTAMP(0)
)
PRIMARY INDEX ( SALES_T_ID );
```

Sample data:

```
SALES_T_ID SALES_SRC_ID
715,603    3-3SDDJH5
593,803    3-3SDDJH5
715,604    3-3SDDJIG
593,804    3-3SDDJIG
715,605    3-3SDDJJR
```

EDIT:
[image]

My requirement is to keep only the latest row
for the combination of Sales_trans_src_id and data_source_type_cd based on updated_date_timestamp.

Comment: Your subquery does not include enough to uniquely identify which rows you want to remove. Any `SALES_T_ID` with more than one row is being removed. What is not clear in your question are the mapping of `DSTC` and `UPDATED_DATE_TIMESTAMP` to your source table. What is the PK of the table? This will have to be projected in your subquery and your WHERE condition modified to include the additional column: `WHERE (SALES_T_ID, {columnA}, ...) IN ()`

Comment: In general terms, I would suggest moving the records you want to keep to a new table, instead of trying to delete rows from your current table.  That would get you past the first point @RobPaller makes.

Comment: @Andrew, I can park it to a table and then delete, but i am not able to understand whats wrong in this approach as i m getting the records to be deleted from the innser query but when i run the entire query it is deleting all records. Is it because the field is defined as decimal?

Comment: @RobPaller, PK defined for that table at source is sales_trans_src_id and surrogate key is sales_trans_id

Comment: Your subquery returns all IDs that have more than one row (based on your criteria).  You are then deleting all rows that have those IDs.  You could try and return more columns in your subquery and join on those as well to attempt to more accurately identify the rows you want to delete.  Or you could wash it through a new table,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DEL FROM X.SALES1
WHERE CAST(SALES_T_ID AS DECIMAL(18,0)) IN(

SEL CAST(T1.SALES_T_ID AS DECIMAL(18,0) )FROM
(
SEL *  FROM 
X.SALES1
QUALIFY rank() OVER( PARTITION BY SALES_SRC_ID,DSTC ORDER BY UPDATED_DATE_TIMESTAMP DESC) > 1
) T1
;
```

can you check this
) ;